# Pronunciation of 站

Tags: pronunciation

While looking for the correct pronunciation of 站 (zhàn / zhan4), I've come across several different recordings in online dictionaries, Forvo, wiktionary, and Google Translate, for example.

Sometimes it's pronounced as "dshan" (the "a" like in "angry" or the German umlaut "ä" / IPA -æn) and sometimes as "dshuhn" (like "un" / IPA -ʌn).

Is this a regional difference? What is the "standard pronunciation" as you would expect to hear it in TV news etc. in mainland China?

Comment: IPA /ɑːn/ would be closer, though I think the English pronunciation for this varies from different areas.

Comment: If you find the correct pronunciation difficult, prefer /ʌn/ over /æn/ as the former sounds dialectical but the latter sounds foreign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard mandarin pronunciation is [an] (”un” for Americans). Regional speech is [æn], preferably in Sichuan and some southern areas, more so for finals like -uan.

Answer (score 0):

according to 國語辭典, it's zhàn

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=W00000007820

then, in 漢語多功能字庫, there're 2 pronunciations:

[http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=站](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/search.php?word=%E7%AB%99)

have fun :)